# Solr: document boosting - can it be disabled at query time?

Tags: solr, lucene

If I've given a boost value for documents at index time, can I disable/ignore that boost value with a query parameter?

I have one type of query where I explicitly want to ignore the document boost value, but the rest should utilize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define multiple request handler with different boost and invoke the same depending upon the Query.
This handling needs to be done at client side before querying Solr.